# how to get only ids from a related model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have Product Model and Size Model. It is a many to many relationship.
What I am trying to do right now is that I want to return product data with an array of related size model's ids like below.

> "data": [ { "id": 1, "name": "サンプル商品名", "product_code": "1ZS2fmMGEK",
> "material": "サンプル素材", "category_id": 1, "desc": "Tempore illum eum
> quia nihil iste neque eligendi. Est velit maiores vero animi debitis.
> Quae est nihil quo odio. Consequatur dicta at sit quas iste velit.
> Mollitia ut aut est perspiciatis.", "views": 0, "purchase_count": 0,
> "created_at": "2021-01-26T11:07:58.000000Z", "updated_at":
> "2021-01-26T11:07:58.000000Z", "sizes": [1,2,3,4,5 ] },

So I wrote my code like this.

```
public function getAll(Array $query):object
{
    try {
        $products = Product::query();
        if($query['sort']){
            $sort_field = $query['sort'][0];
            $order = $query['sort'][1];
            $products->sortable([$sort_field => $order]);
        }
        if($query['filter']){
            $field_name = key($query['filter']);
            $value = $query['filter'][$field_name];
            $products->where($field_name, 'like', '%'.$value.'%');
        }

        return $products->with(['sizes' => function($query){
                $query->select('sizes.id');
                 }])->paginate(10);

     
         
       

    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        // 全てのエラー・例外をキャッチしてログに残す
        \Log::error($e);

        // フロントに異常を通知するため例外はそのまま投げる
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

However, it returned the size's data like this.

"sizes": [
{
"id": 1
}

this is not what I want, as I want an array of ids like this.

"sizes": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

So I tried to change my code and wrote this but no luck.

```
return $products->with(['sizes' => function($query){
     $query->pluck('sizes.id');
  }])->paginate(10);
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Comment: try this `$products->with(['sizes'])->pluck('sizes.id');`

Comment: It does not do what I want to achieve. I want to return an array of ids with product data.

Comment: you want all `id` from `sizes` table?

Comment: yes, thats what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

```
return $products->paginate(10)->through(function ($product, $key) {
            $product['sizes'] = $product->sizes()->pluck('sizes.id');
            $product['colors'] = $product->colors()->pluck('colors.id');
            return $product;
         });
```

this code worked for me